# Allow numbers and commas in JQuery Validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm using a jQuery validation-plugin to validate a form's fields. I've got a scenario where we need to validate a field to allow only commas and numbers.

Here's my HTML-code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Number of Employees" required class="form-control" name="employeeno">
```

And here are the jQuery validation-plugin rules:

```
employeeno:{
    Regex: "[0-9,]+",
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 20
},

jQuery.validator.addMethod("Regex", function(value, element, param) {
    return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
}, "Please enter a valid number");
```

This code actually works if I type at least 2 characters. But if I'm entering only one number - e.g. 2 or 3 - it is displaying an error, allthough I've set my minimum length to one. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is not correct. `.` in regex matches any one character, you need to use `^` for start of the line

```
return value.match(new RegExp("^" + param + "$"));
                               ^^ here
```

---

But you can use the pattern rule from the additional methods file

```
    rules: {
        employeeno: {
            pattern: /^[0-9,]+$/,
            minlength: 1,
            maxlength: 20
        }
    },
    messages: {
        employeeno: {
            pattern: 'Please enter a valid number'
        }
    }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mLd7f72d/)

Comment: WOW, that was quick. Thanks!

Comment: but what is the difference in . and ^?

Comment: `.` matches any one character so your regex looks for 2 or more charcters ending with a digit of `,`

Comment: Tested and its not working any more :(,